# Google safebrowsing api limits

Tags: php, google-api, safe-browsing

Who know how many url can i check and what time limit between request i need to use with safebrowsing api. I use it with PHP, but after checking 2k urls, i got

Sorry but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.

Answer (score 0):

are supposed to be 10.000

with both the Safe Browsing Lookup API
https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/lookup_guide#UsageRestrictions

and Safe Browsing API v2
https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/developers_guide_v2#Overview

but you could ask for more is free they said.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that they allow you to do 10k request per day. On each request you can query for up to 500 URLs, so, in total they let you lookup 5M URLs daily, not bad.

Answer (score 0):

I currently use Google Safe Browsing API and following are the limitations in the API.

- A single API key can make requests for up to 10,000 clients per 24-hour period.
- You can query up to 500 URLs in a single POST
  request.

I previously used one request per time and ended by exceeding the quota defined by the API. But now per request I set maximum of 500 URLs. It helped me not to exceed the limit of the API and it is super fast too.